# Alternative for get_posts, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get some products of an `post_author` from DB. The problem is that `get_posts` is not working properly, from my debug that's a problem from the theme that I am using.

Is there any alternative to get products from DB?

**What I tried:**

```
 -----1----
    $related_products = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'author' => 19,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );

 -----2----
     $product_query = new WP_Query( array(
         'author'         => 19,
         'post_type'      => 'product',
         'post_status'    => 'publish',
     ) );
     $related_products = $product_query->posts;


 -----3----
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 
       'post_type' => 'product',
       'author' => 19,
    ) );

    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
    $related_products = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query( $args );
```

I get results, but random products.

Comment: I do not understand what's your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Get all products of an post_author.

Comment: what you get now?

Comment: Nothing or one product (from other post_author). So basically something else. But if I please this code on one of default themes, I get correct data. (So the problem is from the theme that I am using).

Comment: try to ask where you get that theme.

Comment: That's not a solution. I already did, but they don't care if is not something from there setting/ user interface. So I have 2 options, find the bug in their code, or try to get an alternative for my code.

Comment: you should not use a theme that creates a bug on a wordpress function, a fundamental wordpress function.

Comment: Is not like I know from the start if this theme had bugs and I work for few months with it so no turning back.